# All possible combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have two sets (1,2,3) and (A,B,C,D,E). I want to calculate all possible combinations.

This would be my approach:

**combinations with a single 1:**

```
1A

1B

1C

1D

1E

1AB

1AC

1AD

1AE

1ABC

1ABD

1ABE

1ABCD

1ABCE

1ABCDE
```

**The same with a single 2 (then 3,4,5):**

```
2A

2B

2C

...
```

**Same with 1 and 2:**

```
12A

12B

12C

...
```

**Then with 1 and 2 and 3:**

```
123A

123B

123C

...
```

Am I on the right way? What would be the right formula?

Comment: What about $1BD$ for example?

Comment: That would also be possible. The order doesn't matter. But `1BD` and `1DB` should be the same in my case.

Comment: OK, then my answer below is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must chose from both sets, then you have $2^3-1$ possibilities so chose the elements from $(1,2,3)$ and $2^5-1$ possibilities to chose from the set $(A,B,C,D,E)$.

All in All you have 
$$(2^3-1)(2^5-1).$$

Comment: Why is there a 2 as the basis? Does this only apply in my case?

Comment: The number of subsets of a set of cardinality $k$ is $2^k$. Thats because for each element you have two possibilities, either to be in the subset or not to be.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want increasing numbers followed by increasing numbers. Then, there are $2^3 - 1$ possible values for the numbers (1, 12, 123) and $2^5 - 1$ for the letters (A, AB, ABC, ABCD, ABCD, etc.). Therefore, there should be 31*7 = 217.

How did I get the $2^5 - 1$? We can basically just choose which letters we want and which we don't want - after that, there's only one ordering of the letters that works. Therefore, for each letter, we either put it in the string, or we don't. That's where the $2^5$ comes from. We subtract $1$ to remove the case where there are no letters.

Comment: Note that OP counts $1AC$, thus counting some non-consecutive letters. Also, $23$ and $BC$ are consecutive numbers and letters you are not counting for no aparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's one thing to 'calculate' the number of combinations for your problem. That's not too hard to do. What you need to do is to account for how you are picking items from each group. You can pick 1, 2, or 3 items from the first group. The number of different ways to pick k items from a set of n is given as 'n choose k', denoted by the following:

$$n \choose k$$

Since you're just stacking two groups together, the number of ways to pick $k_1$ from group 1 and $k_2$ from group 2 is:

$$\binom{n_1}{k_1}\binom{n_2}{k_2}$$

To find the total number of combinations, just sum that equation over all combinations of $k_1$ and $k_2$:

$$\sum_{k_1 = 1}^{3}\sum_{k_2 = 1}^{5}\binom{3}{k_1}\binom{5}{k_2}$$

What you seem to be asking for, though, is how to 'generate' all the combinations. Generating all the combinations requires some kind of computer code (or patience by hand).

Answer (score 0):

Since order doesn't matter, basically you want all **combinations** i.e. ${n_1\choose k1}\cdot{n_2\choose k2}$

Now the sum of binomial coefficients ${n\choose 0} + {n\choose 1} + ....{n\choose n} = 2^n$

Since we want to choose at least one number and one alpha from each set, i.e.${n\choose 0}$=1 is disallowed,

ans = $(2^3 - 1)(2^5 - 1)$